# Ansible command doesn't work when i try to start npm using daemon

Tags: node.js, npm, ansible, devops

I have following command and it doesn't work when i run it using ansible

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  remote_user: ubuntu
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: webuser
  tasks:
      - name: Start web ui
        command: /usr/bin/daemon --name=web_ui --output=log.txt --chdir=/web --command="/usr/share/node/bin/npm run start"
```

Running ansible

```
root@ip-172:~# ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local ansible-local/setup_feee__.yml

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [Start web ui] ********************************************************** 
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   

root@ip-172:~# lsof -i | grep 3000
root@ip-172:~#
```

But then i execute it manually it works

```
webuser@ip-172:~$ /usr/bin/daemon --name=web_ui --output=log.txt --chdir=/web --command="/usr/share/node/bin/npm run start"

webuser@ip-172:~$ lsof -i | grep 3000
node    19169 webuser   11u  IPv4 127637      0t0  TCP localhost:3000 (LISTEN)
```

What is wrong with my ansible command?

Answer (score 0):

I see a difference between `npm run start` and `/usr/share/node/bin/npm start`.

If `npm` is not in root’s `PATH`, it will not work.
Either specify a full path for `npm`, or add its location to your `PATH`.

Do you want to call `npm run start` or `npm start`?

Also, there’s probably a log file (or even `ansible`’s output) saying that `npm` is not found. Always look for those.